# Filtering nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using text to search over some data. Some of the data is nested, and the other part is not.

1. If it returns a result from the nested part of the data, it should only return that *nested* value (and it's parent value).

I've put it on codeSandbox too- https://codesandbox.io/s/Q0w16jLP0

The function:

```
function filterTypes(items, search) {
  return items.filter(items => {
    const nestedName = items.typechild.map(x => x.name.toLowerCase());
    const name = items.name.toLowerCase();
    return search.every(x => {
      return name.includes(x) || nestedName.some(v => v.includes(x));
    });
  });
}
```

The datastructure:

```
{
    "name": "Food",
    "typechild": [{
        "name": "Fruit", "id":12,
    }, {
        "name": "Vegetable", "id":13,
    }]
}
```

How it works now:

- it returns all the children of `Food`.

Desired result:

*If the filter has value `Fruit`, it should return...*

- `Food` as the title
- `Fruit` below that title

Desired datastructure

```
{
    "name": "Food",
    "typechild": [{
        "name": "Fruit", "id":12,
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive approach:

```
function check(el,name){
 if(el.name.includes(name)){
  return [el];
 }
 if(el.typechild && el.typechild.find){
 var child=el.typechild.find(function(child){
   return check(child,name);
 });
}
 if(child){
  child=check(child,name);
  child.unshift(el);
  return child;
}
return false;
}
```

It will return

```
[Food Object, Fruit Object]
```

Comment: But I need it to return the fill values of the array. Let me update the data

Comment: That still just returns the `name` whereas it should return the whole object. Could you please show as an example with my code? Such as in this- https://codesandbox.io/s/Q0w16jLP0

Comment: @ycon simply change return [name] to return [el] and .unshift(el.name) to .unshift(el)

Comment: That returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". Could you take a look? I tried it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/Q0w16jLP0

Comment: @Ycon el means *an object* not *an array* https://codesandbox.io/s/lm78Lqz1

Comment: I checked the pen, but it still doesn't return the result. Does it have to be treated as an object? I want to keep it as close as possible to my example https://codesandbox.io/s/Q0w16jLP0

Answer (score 0):

Solution with mutating the the original data.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Food", typechild: [{ name: "Fruit", level: 2, color: "#fff" }, { name: "Vegetable", level: 2, color: "#fff" }] }, { name: "Entertainment", typechild: [{ name: "Book", level: 2, color: "#fff" }, { name: "Movie", level: 2, color: "#fff" }, { name: "Bar", level: 3, color: "#fff" }] }, { name: "Misc", typechild: [{ name: "Foo", level: 2, color: "#fff" }] }],
    search = 'Fruit',
    index = data.length,
    temp;

while (index--) {
    temp = data[index].typechild.filter(o => o.name === search);
    if (temp.length) {
        data[index].typechild = temp;
    } else {
        data.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Ycon, actually i don't know what the expected data structure look like. please add this information to the question.

Comment: Sure, I just added the desired data structure: `{ "name": "Food", "typechild": [{ "name": "Fruit", "id":12, }] }`

Comment: so you expect only one object as result? not more if possible?

Comment: It should return all the objects possible-

Comment: then you need an array, like my proposal. what does not work with your data?

Comment: What does not work is- it should remove the `typechild` objects which are not a result of the array. If you see my proposed, the `desired data structure` does not contain `Vegetable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147450/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-ycon).